# Looking for a better architecture to generate reports from the production database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, etl, business-intelligence, aws-glue

In the company I work for, one of the jobs I have to do is to write programs to generate business reports (e.g. the number of users that visited our website last month) using the data stored in the production database.

We use AWS lambda functions and complicated MySQL queries to generate the report (*.csv files).

[image]

There are some drawbacks with this architecture:

1. The MySQL queries are often complicated. I mean they include a lot of `join`s and subqueries, which make the code difficult to understand and maintain.
2. Some of the queries may fail to work after the database schema changes.
3. The maximum timeout of AWS lambda function is 5 minutes. When the data size becomes too large, we have to split 1 lambda function into multiple lambda functions.

How can I use other Amazon web services to solve these problems?

I've tried AWS Glue but haven't figured out an easy way to convert the complicated MySQL queries into the python script for the job in AWS Glue.

Amazon Athena can only process data stored in S3. It cannot directly process data stored in Amazon RDS.

Comment: I think this more of a dba question

Comment: Use MySQL stored procedures instead of AWS lambda  functions....But your question is way to broad..

Comment: While, am not able to provide an solution now, please note that as of 10th Oct 2018 AWS have announced an update that AWS Lambda duration has been increased to 15 minutes now.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Answer (score 1):

We use Matillion (third party software) as an ETL-tool in my company, designed to work with AWS (or Google) Cloud. But that heavily relies on AWS Redshift. If you can move your data to Redshift and work from there, Matillion can be a very good option for you. In Matillion you can set up workflows that does all the work and visualized this in a diagram. The drawback is that Matillion has a cost. But since you are refering to you company, I figured you will be able to invest in additional tools. I also use Matillion together with Lambda, S3, Redshift, Glue, etc. Since you can run Python-scripts in Matillion, you can combine these as you wish.

Ps. I dont work for Matillion or wont in any way benefit from recommending Matillion.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you have asked this 1 year ago - a faster approach would be to:

1. Identify the refresh time and strategy of your MySQL tables and using that information setup data pipes in Matillion to bring that data over incrementally to either snowflake/GCP/Redshift.
2. Create Snowflake/GCP/Redshift versions of reporting SQLs and then generate report on those tables.